# Deleting ALL products on Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

There are a lot of posts regarding this issue on Magento. Most of them work but the problem with Categories not resetting their values to ZERO after executing the delete codes/SQL statements still persists and not being addressed up until now.

Does anyone here has the correct code or procedure to properly delete all products from the inventory and have the Category listing also reset to zero after executing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the ID numbers? you'd have to reset the tables' auto_increment primary keys.

Comment: No. I'm pertaining to the count for the products under each category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of the method used to delete the products, rebuilding the "Category Products" index should fix the counts.  Go to System > Index Management.  Check the box next to "Category Products", change the action (top right) to "Reindex" and  click submit.

Comment: I changed my mind. For the benefit of those who are having similar problem, I'm choosing this as the most suitable answer.

Answer (score 59):

Deleting all products from Magento can be easily achieved, just run:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity`
```

Because of the foreign key constraints set up in Magento's database, all other tables that have product information in them are cleaned up nicely. It will of course take some time to delete a lot of products, but it at least gets cleaned up nicely.

If the query can't run because of maximum execution time, you can always run something like:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` LIMIT 10000
```

Update:
this logic also gets used in Magento's core, so it's safe to use! https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L462

Comment: this doesn't delete the categories

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't, this is meant to delete all products.

Comment: To delete categories, use: `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity;`

Comment: This needs to be the top answer.

Comment: I would NOT run `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity;` because it deletes your root category, causing your some grief. maybe use `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity WHERE level != 0`

Comment: When you do this, the indexes remain in url_rewrite table, now the table is huge but i have no products in my catalog. Any ideas to fix this ?

Answer (score 14):

In an stand alone script:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);


$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();    
foreach ($products as $product) {
    try {
        $product->delete();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Product #".$product->getId()." could not be remvoved: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Did that for more that 1400 products, worked fine. You have to do a reindexing after that.

Beware the above script will **delete ALL** your products

Comment: +1 for using Magento scripting which should preserve data integrity instead of attacking the database, finding things don't work and turning the integrity checks off to find later that things really don't work.

Comment: integrity issues on may products

Comment: For a larger number of products (~ 100000)  the script can be improved by adding:            `ini_set("memory_limit", "2024M");
ini_set("max_execution_time", "86400");` and ` Mage::log('to delete: ' . $product-> getId());` for some feedback. And it might be senseful to start it in a screen.

Answer (score 6):

To delete all products you can use this query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_enabled_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;

TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;

INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,'Default');
```

Regards :)

Comment: This query doesn't work due to data integrity issue. It shows me the error `#1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`dbname`.`catalog_product_bundle_option_value`, CONSTRAINT `FK_MKM_CAT_PRD_BNDL_OPT_VAL_OPT_ID_MKM_CAT_PRD_BNDL_OPT_OPT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `dbname`.`catalog_produ)`. Any idea to solve it?

Comment: add `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` at top of the above code and add `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;` bottom of code.

Comment: Remove checks for data integrity, cross your fingers and hope data corruption doesn't ensue = `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

Answer (score 3):

In order to delete products, you can simply use backend:
Catalog > Manage Products > Select all checboxes and choose Action = Delete and hit submit.
This may work very good for some thousands of products.

Comment: Well for that much products it will be really slow and memory/server timeout issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

Worked like a charm...

Php myadmin - select databse (magento) SWL at top and then pasted the following:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity`
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Magento 1.7.0.2

```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_flat_1`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_enabled_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite`;
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,'Default');
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Please never use queries that set the foreign key checks to 0. The queries run faster, but you are risking database corruption.

Comment: You can't truncate with FK on, because imho mysql deletes the table and creates a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution in my opinion is this:

- Go to `System -> Index Management` and set all indexes to "Manual Update" index mode
- Go to `Catalog -> Manage Products`, select all products and use the `Delete` action to delete all products.

This is not as fast as manually deleting the products from the database but it's probably the fastest proper way to delete all products where you don't have to worry about orphaned database entries or foreign key conflicts.